# .NET core User Claims Reusability

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have been using Azure B2C authentication for a while. Whenever I need to identify the user that is logged in I can just call

```
User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == ClaimConstants.ObjectId)?.Value
```

or when I need to get the user`s email I can just call

```
User?.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == "emails").Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Everything works fine and I can work with the user`s information however I noticed whenever I need to get some information about the user I need to repeat myself and use the lines above again and again. With multiple methods in a controller I can end up with a repetitive code. I can see that  the User comes from the ControllerBase and it is a class called ClaimsPrincipal that contains ienumerable of <claims  which I am using to identify the user. I would like to ideally create my own class that will be responsible for identifying those users or I would like to just instantiate this once in the controller and assign it to my property so I can reuse it. I tried to do this in the constructor of my controller and I was really surprised, it was null even after I successfully logged in with the user.

```
  private readonly string _userId;
   private readonly string _userEmail;


  public HomeMickeyMouseController(
            IRecaptchaTrashService recaptchaService,
            IOrderGarbageService orderService
        {
            _recaptchaService = recaptchaService;
            _orderService = orderService;               
            _userId = User?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == ClaimConstants.ObjectId)?.Value;
            _userEmail = User?.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == "emails").Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault(); //NULL EVEN AFTER LOGIN??!!! WHILE NOT NULL IN A METHOD?
        }



  public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var test = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == ClaimConstants.ObjectId)?.Value; //this is not NULL 
            return View();
        }
```

Is this possible to achieve this somehow, or do I have to just repeat  User.Claims in every method of the controller? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use HttpContext to get the claim in your constructor.

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;
//.........
    
public HomeMickeyMouseController(IHttpContextAccessor context)
        {
            //.........
            _context = context;

            var test = _context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(e => e.Type == "emails").Select(e => e.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Xinran it works fine. I noticed there is a comment for this interface "This interface should be used with caution. It relies on System.Threading.AsyncLocal`1
    //     which can have a negative performance impact on async calls." Is this ok, or something I should be aware of?

Comment: In your code, you just want to get the value of claim in constructor instead of repeating the same code in different actions, So in my opinion, you can use it in this situation.